# Reputation on top username hover pop-out ignores unaccepts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Here's how today's reputation on my profile looks:

[image]

It's correctly calculated as 64. However, hovering over my username on the top bar incorrectly shows 79:

[image]